# how to create jwt token automatically once it gets expired

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am storing jwt access token in localstorage once it is getting created and then I am using it everywhere. Here I am facing issue, once jwt token gets expired I am not able to search. So I want once jwt token expires it should be created automatically. What should be the way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe check for expiry on every user interaction (EG action dispatched or route changed) and if expiry time is too close renew the JWT. This way if the user didn't have interactions for a long time the token will expire which is acceptable.

Comment: thank you for your response. Actually I am checking in the action creator if access token is expired or not but the problem is I am calling action creator on some event. Means I need to perform any event to check the error. I have kept separate action creator for creating jwt token. I can't call one action creator inside another action creator. Please guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution - a simple redux middleware that will refresh an existing, non-expired token which is going to expire soon.

It uses the [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) library and assumes the existence of a `renewToken` function that does the actual renewal.

See the comments in the code for more details.

```js
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import { renewToken } from authManager

// If less than this time in seconds to expiry - renew the token
const EXPIRY_THRESHOLD = 600 

// Milli seconds between expiry checks
// Should be longer than the time it takes for a request for new token to succeed / fail
// This is how we avoid multiple token requests
const CHECK_INTERVAL = 10000 

// Timestamp of last time we checked the token for expiry
let lastCheckTs = -CHECK_INTERVAL


/**
 * Get time in seconds until the id_token expires.
 * A negative value means it has already expired (or doesn't exist)
 */
function getTimeToExpiry(key) {
  let jwt = localStorage.getItem(key)
  if(jwt) {
      let jwtExp = jwtDecode(jwt).exp
      let expiryDate = new Date(0)
      expiryDate.setUTCSeconds(jwtExp)

      return Math.floor((expiryDate.getTime() - Date.now()) / 1000)
  }
  return -1
}

export default store => next => action => {
    const now = Date.now()
    if (now - lastCheckTs < CHECK_INTERVAL) {
        // We checked recently, just continue
        return next(action)
    }
    lastCheckTs = now

    const timeToExpire = getTimeToExpiry('id_token')


    // This middleware is only concerned with keeping a valid session alive.

    // If the existing token is stale or non-existent - 
    // do nothing and let other parts of the app take care of
    // getting a completely new valid token (EG by prompting the user to login)

    // If the existing token has a long time to expiry - do nothing until the next check

    // However, if the existing token is valid but will expire soon - try to renew it.
    if (timeToExpire > 0 && timeToExpire < EXPIRY_THRESHOLD) {
        // Try to renew the token
        const current_id_token = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
        renewToken(current_id_token, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                // Do nothing - 
                // If we got here it means that the current token is still fresh, 
                // so we'll just try again in the next expiry check
            } else {
                // Store the new token
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', result.id_token)  
            }
        });
    }

    return next(action)
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this way.